# C# wpf how to know a control (es. listbox) size when not specified

Tags: c#, wpf, width

I have two borders in a winwdow, the first one contains a listbox which has size set through margins. So I can change the window size--->the border changes---> the listbox changes. I'd like to know what it's width is but the width property reports Nan while the actualWidth report 0.

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,168.8,10.4" >
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="338" Margin="0,0,0.4,0"/>                        
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Border2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="263,10,9.2,10" />
            </Grid>
```

This is something valid for each control: how to know its present size when it's not specified? 
thanx

Comment: 1 - What do you want that for? 2 - if `ActualWidth` is zero then you're looking at the wrong control.

Comment: It is possible that the component is not yet displayed at the point where you get its size. You can get the right actualWidth in the **loaded** event of the object.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette you are right! That's the reason I put the         private void lbButtons_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 and here the ActualWidth is correct! You can post it as a solution I'll vote it. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the component is not yet displayed at the point where you get its size. You can get the right actualWidth in the loaded event of the object.